# How to deactivate or override the arrow back button in the appBar in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

Is there a way to deactivate the arrow back button when on a specific page? 
I built a splash screen and whenever the splash screen navigates to the HomePage, in the HomePage appBar the arrow for going back shows, How can I deactivate it or clear the arrow from going back to the previous page(welcome screen).

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return WillPopScope(
onWillPop: () {return Future.value();
}, // async => true,
child: Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("Application!"),
    elevation: 20,
    centerTitle: true,
    actions: <Widget>[
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      ),
      PopupMenuButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
        itemBuilder: (context) => [
          PopupMenuItem(
            child: Text("Home"),
          ),
          PopupMenuItem(
            child: Text("Hire"),
          ),
          PopupMenuItem(
            child: Text("Settings"),
          ),
          PopupMenuItem(
            child: Text("About"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: Container(
      child: Text("Chech out my new Mobile Applications!")
    ),
  ),
),
);
}
```

[image]